# resolve promise after callback function has been executed

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this to reset a text input :

```
function inputReset(){

    const textarea = $("textarea").first();
    textarea.fadeOut(2000, "swing", textareaAnimeEnded);

    function textareaAnimeEnded(){ 
        // I'll do some stuff here and after 500 ms I should resolve the inputReset function
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500));
    }
}
```

I want to use the `inputReset` in another function like this:

```
async function foo() {

 await inputReset();

}
```

How can I resolve the promise after 500 ms of execution of `textareaAnimeEnded` function?

Comment: "*How can I resolve the promise after 500 ms of execution of `textareaAnimeEnded` function?*" this is what would happen if you execute that function. If it doesn't work, you need to explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to make `inputReset` function to return `Promise` type.
2. And resolve the Promise of `inputReset` after `textAreaAnimeEnded` function called.

I have attached the working example

```js
function inputReset() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const textarea = $("textarea").first();
    textarea.fadeOut(2000, "swing", async () => {
      console.log('Here');
      await textareaAnimeEnded();
      return resolve();
    });
  });
}

function textareaAnimeEnded() {
  // I'll do some stuff here and after 500 ms I should resolve the inputReset function
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500));
}

async function foo() {
  await inputReset();
  console.log('Hello');
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>asdfasdfasdfasdf</textarea>
<button onclick="foo()">Foo</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move promise higher:

```
function inputReset() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const textarea = $("textarea").first();
    textarea.fadeOut(2000, "swing", textareaAnimeEnded);

    function textareaAnimeEnded() {
      // I'll do some stuff here and after 500 ms I should resolve the inputReset function
      setTimeout(resolve, 500);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use setTimeout() without having to use a Promise.

```
function foo() {
   setTimeout(() => {
      textareaAnimeEnded();
   }, 500)
}
```